# Google Script: setOption chartArea doesn't work in Google Spreadsheet embedded chartbuilder

Tags: charts, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I want to build a chart in my Google spreadsheet.  The chart responds to all options except the chartArea.  I want my labels to show on the left side of the V-Axis.  Now these are hidden behind the chartArea. (photo)

[This chart has the labels hidden behind the chartArea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YX61z.png)

```
    var chartBuilder = SS.newChart();
chartBuilder.addRange(range)
.setPosition(10, 2, 0, 0)
   .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.BAR)
     .setOption('height', BVhoogte)
   .setOption('width', 720)
   .setOption('isStacked', true)
   .setOption('legend', { position: "bottom" })
.setOption( 'hAxis', {textStyle:{color:"white"}, gridlines:{color:"white"}})
   .setOption('height', 150)
   .setOption('width',720)
   .setOption('colors', ["#6d6f75","#000000", "#dcdee2"])
   .asBarChart().setOption('chartArea',{ left:200, width: 500}) ;
    SS.insertChart(chartBuilder.build());
```

I've tried

```
         .asBarChart().setOption('chartArea.left', 100)
```

but this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following modification?

#### From :

```
.asBarChart().setOption('chartArea.left', 100)
```

#### To :

```
.asBarChart().setOption('chartArea', {left:'20%', top:'10%', width:"60%", height:"60%"})
```

About each parameter, please adjust for your design. If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks, Tanaike.  This works.  The absolute values didn't.  But the relative ones did.

Comment: Yes. I could notice about this from your question. Thank you, too.